# More advanced search engine features when searching with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, full-text-search

I have to "search" in a MySQL database containing thousands of comments (200 characters max) with a traditional "search field" (like on most websites). I tried with SQL like:

```
SELECT * FROM comments  WHERE text LIKE 'Bonjour monsieur'
```

But then, to provide good search features, we have to *first display* the results with  `Bonjour monsieur`, then display the results with both the words `Bonjour` and `monsieur` (but maybe not the one next to the other), and **then** the results with `Bonjour` or `Monsieur` etc.

Also, there is a need of case insensitive search, and lots of similar things (`é` `e` `ê` could be considered as same letters for search), etc.

To provide a good search experience for the user, there are many similar little things to code.

**Is there a built-in feature in PHP / MySQL to provide these "search engine" features or do I have to code them from scratch?**

*Note : This is not a topic asking "what is the specific tool for ..." (I know that such questions are often considered OffTopic in SO), I just want to know if these features already exist, or if I have to write all myself from scratch.*

Comment: You probably looking at mysql full text search http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I tried this @AbhikChakraborty, but unfortunately, 1) it doesn't handle  similar word if accents are omitted (example if "Château" is in the DB, searching "Chateau" gives no result...),   2) it doesn't work if I search uncomplete words / typos : searching "Monsieu" will give no result if "Monsieur" is in the DB...  How to add searching with word "similarity"  (like in Google for example) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL 5.1, you can install a stemmer plugin.

http://forge.mysql.com/projects/project.php?id=215
http://forge.mysql.com/projects/project.php?id=42

Comment: I get "MySQL :: Page Not Found". Are you sure of the URL? Can you provide a small example of how to use the plugin you are talking about?